# MPMoviePlayerViewController with controls set to MPMovieControlStyleNone

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I want to use a MPMoviePlayerViewController with the control style set to:

MPMovieControlStyleNone

Now I need a way for the end user to close this MPMoviePlayerViewController window if they don't want to watch the whole video. I would like to have them double tap the screen and the MPMoviePlayerViewController would close.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a transparent button over the MPMoviePlayerViewController view and use the action to close the player :

```
- (void) buttonWasPressed
{
    // Close the MPMoviePlayerViewController here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem I am having is putting the transparent button over the MPMoviePlayerViewController view. Would anyone have some example code? Thanks again.

Comment: Try : [yourMPMoviePlayerVC.view addSubview: theButton.view]; [yourMPMoviePlayerVC.view bringSubviewToFront:theButton.view];

Answer (score 0):

Create a container view.  Place the movieplayer view in that view and then put the button on top of it.  I am doing this for an intro movie with a button to skip the intro and it works fine.